# Firebase + Nextjs - User session sharing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

## Problem:

I need to make database requests on the server side of my app which is written using **Next.js and Firebase** (not the best combination, I know) to prepare initial data for the client side.

Problem is that I would like to use the same code that runs on the client side on the server (using the firebase client SDK on the server for the DB requests).

**But I do not know how to share the user session with the server side.**

The server does not have the user logged-in in the client SDK and thus returns 403 for restricted resources even though the client side has access to them (it knows the current user)

## I have tried the following:

### Custom token hack (can´t use ID token to sing in)

Currently I have to add the user ID token to a cookie.
This way the token is appended to every subsequent request and the server side can generate a custom token (I cannot login with the ID token) through which I can then login on the server side of the app as well as on the client side (which is already logged-in if persistence is enabled).

This is a huge overkill and I should be able to login on the server the same way as on the client because it is in fact acting like a client itself (it does not do any privileged operations).

### Login second time on the server

Other solution was to send credentials via cookie (security risk) and then login on the server second time. This does not work with one time auth sessions (like one-time email links because the server effectively logs in the second time).

### The official expample is not helpful

In the Next.js repo there is a example for firbease auth which has now commented out the server side data fetching. Even if it was not commented out it is not checking for user permission, it just straight up fetches the data if a user is found https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same setup (Next.js and Firebase) and it was not straightforward setting up global session via react context API. I followed this guide and I was successful https://reacttricks.com/sharing-global-data-in-next-with-custom-app-and-usecontext-hook/